# PHP Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() woocommerce plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I get this warning in error log contineously please help

> PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/loop/orderby.php on line 17

Here is orderby.php code

```
<?php
/**
 * Show options for ordering
 *
 * @author      WooThemes
 * @package     WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version     2.2.0
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

?>
<form class="woocommerce-ordering" method="get">
    <select name="orderby" class="orderby">
        <?php foreach ( $catalog_orderby_options as $id => $name ) : ?>
            <option value="<?php echo esc_attr( $id ); ?>" <?php selected( $orderby, $id ); ?>><?php echo esc_html( $name ); ?></option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
    <?php
        // Keep query string vars intact
        foreach ( $_GET as $key => $val ) {
            if ( 'orderby' === $key || 'submit' === $key ) {
                continue;
            }
            if ( is_array( $val ) ) {
                foreach( $val as $innerVal ) {
                    echo '<input type="hidden" name="' . esc_attr( $key ) . '[]" value="' . esc_attr( $innerVal ) . '" />';
                }
            } else {
                echo '<input type="hidden" name="' . esc_attr( $key ) . '" value="' . esc_attr( $val ) . '" />';
            }
        }
    ?>
</form>
```

Comment: `$catalog_orderby_options` is not an array

Comment: Make what changes in it I know only basic of php